# Why Spring jar application closes after Start?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My spring application works inside intellij with gradle bootRun.
When I build the jar file with Task -> Build -> Jar, going to /build/libs, opening powershell and running "java -jar jar-file.jar", then the following console log appears and the application ends.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)

15:57:24.858 [main] INFO com.hipertrofiabet.ApplicationStart -- Starting ApplicationStart using Java 17.0.7 with PID 2736 (E:\my github repos\hipertrofia bet\static server\build\libs\hipertrofiabet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by SaluC in E:\my github repos\hipertrofia bet\static server\build\libs)
15:57:24.861 [main] INFO com.hipertrofiabet.ApplicationStart -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
15:57:25.081 [main] INFO com.hipertrofiabet.ApplicationStart -- Started ApplicationStart in 0.337 seconds (process running for 0.524)
```

It has a ApplicationStart and a Controller.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationStart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStart.class, args);
    }

}

@Controller
public class StaticController {

    @RequestMapping(path="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexPage() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

this is my build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "application"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.2.0"
}

group "com.hipertrofiabet"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:3.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:6.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:6.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.2.0")
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:3.1.5")
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.1.5")
    implementation("org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2")
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.15.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30")
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30")
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.9.0")
}

jar {

    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class" : "com.hipertrofiabet.ApplicationStart"
    }

    duplicatesStrategy = "exclude"

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

}
```

this is my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8081
  address: 0.0.0.0
logging:
  level:
    web: INFO
```

I've been trying to understand what's happening for the last 4 days, I'm learning spring and I definitely have no more ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Try adding `org.springframework.boot` plugin in your gradle file. After compilation this plugin will generate a fat jar/uber jar which contains all the necessary dependencies for your spring boot application to run as a jar file

Comment: I added it but this happened:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot'] was not found in any of the following sources.

Comment: ok i was able to fix following this tutorial: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot
But nothing changes at all.

Comment: Another issue, @RequestMapping should have a method eg. `@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` or instead use `@GetMapping(path="/")`

Comment: `plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.2.0"
}` 
and later on make sure to package your application with `gradle build` the fat jar generated is the one to use for `java -jar` command

Comment: You can also use `gradle bootRun` to run your application

Comment: i'm already using gradle bootRun for debug, it is working, but the jar isn't working. i'm generating the jar with Task -> build -> jar
Then going to build/libs, opening powershell and executing "java -jar hipertrofiabet-1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar", then that console log appears and the application ends. This jar has 25MB.
I added parameter method to RequestMapping.

Comment: For starters stop mixing modules from different versions. Remove the versions from the dependencies. You should add the spring dependency management plugin, that way Spring Boot will properly manage the versions and prevents you from mixing incompatible versions. Use `gradlew buikld` to build the jar not the `Build -> Jar` option from Intellij as that will bypass the Spring Boot plugin generating the proper fatjar.

Comment: Just tested your application and it works with the solution I wrote below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add `@RestController` annotation instead of `@Controller`, this is because `@RestController` includes the `@ResponseBody` annotation which tells the controller that the return object is serialized to JSON and returned as an HTTP Response.

**IMPORTANT**

When generating a jar file with maven or gradle, spring boot generates two jar files, one which only contains the code you wrote and another which contains both the code you wrote (your classes, interfaces etc.) and the dependencies needed to run the application - this is what we call a fat jar. Make sure to use the fat jar to run your application when using `java -jar` command.

Run `gradlew build` or `.\gradlew build` to generate this jar files.

In gradle this jar files are located in `/build/libs/*` directory. The fat jar to use is the one without the `*-plain.jar`. As I understand you have been running the `hipertrofiabet-1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar` instead of `hipertrofiabet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file.

Run `java -jar hipertrofiabet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` command to run your spring boot application.